# ajax don't call the success or error function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my ajax code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function la(){
alert("a");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: {action:'call'},
    success:function(){
        alert('aaaaa');
    },
    error: function{}{
        alert('bbb');
    }
    });
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="la()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and the ajax.php：

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'call'){
    echo "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
} else{
    echo "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc";
}
?>
```

when I click the button, the function la() don't execute, nor the alert("a")

(my jquery is installed successfully)

Comment: Was the request sent at all? Check the network tab through developer tools or use a web debugging proxy. Also check the console output for error messages.

Comment: You have a syntax error on your error callback function, change `error: function{} `to `error: function()`

Comment: Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can help yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error on your error callback function, change `error: function{}` to `error: function()`